# JPanel wont repaint

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

My JPanel wont repaint, I am calling the repaint method from a loop using a thread. I am 100% sure that the loop works but when calling repaint(); nothing happens

```
package jgame.org.game;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable
{   
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        if (gameState == 0)
        {
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.home")
                    + "/jGame/FruitSlayer/Sprites/splash.png").getImage(), 0,
                    0, null);
        } else
        {
            g.drawImage(new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.home")
                    + "/jGame/FruitSlayer/Sprites/white.png").getImage(), 0,
                    0, null);
        }
        System.out.println("REPAINT");
    }

    public int currentLoopTime, gameState;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (gameState != 1)
            {
                currentLoopTime += 1;
                if (currentLoopTime == 2000)
                {
                    gameState = 1;
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

And my Game class:

```
package jgame.org.game;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JFrame
{
    public Dimension size = new Dimension(605, 625);

    public Game()
    {
        super("Fruit Slayer");
        setSize(size);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        (new Thread(new GamePanel())).start();
        add(new GamePanel());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Game();
    }

}
```

REPAINT isn't printing in the console but when I add it to the loop it works perfectly. What is causing it not to call paint(Graphics); even though im using repaint();???

Comment: Please do not load images in the `paint(Graphics)` method, or really any painting method...

Answer (score 2):

there are a few the remains of the ancient past, no good idea build

- override `public void paintComponent (Graphics g`) instead of `public void paint(Graphics g)` for Swing JPanel
- next line should be `super.paint()`/`super.paintComponent()`
- don't load any `Object`s inside `paint`/`paintComponent`, nor `FileIO` (doesn't matter if is from resources) prepare `Image`, etc... to local variable(s)
- override `getPreferredSize` for `JPanel`, otherwise painting returns zero dimension
- use `Swing Timer` for todays `Java6/7` instead of `Runnable#Thread`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public Game()
{
    super("Fruit Slayer");
    setSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel();
    (new Thread(panel)).start();
    setContentPane(panel);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Btw. I had to change (new Thread(panel)).start(); to (new Thread(new GamePanel())).start(); or it would give me an error. Still won't repaint :(

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that. Works now :) Thanks